# CSS - How to Draw a Multi-Coloured Line?

Tags: css

I have a navbar and for a particular element, instead of the default white underline I wish to colour the line using 5 colours and was wondering if this was possible?

The structure is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="underlinemenu" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-67">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-69 current_page_item">
            <a href="#">The Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-60">
             <a href="#">Meet the Bloggers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2">
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#underlinemenu{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#underlinemenu ul{
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 770px;
    height: 57px;
    background-color: #242129;
    margin: -14px 0 -30px 0;
}


#underlinemenu ul li{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 21px 40px 0px 8px; 
}

#underlinemenu ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

#underlinemenu ul li a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
}

.current_page_item {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 21px 10px 16px 5px !important;
    margin: 0 30px 0 3px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
```

​

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/SMrYF/

**Colour Codes**

```
#a3ad24
#4594cc
#c4262e
#d9709c
#ffa100
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

mockup can be found here: http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/2866/navbarf.jpg

Comment: A mock-up image showing exactly what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: @MattCoughlin - updated the question with a mockup

Comment: Best bet is to go with a background-image.

Comment: @BramVanroy thanks, I thought that would be the case but was just wondering if it was possible in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pure CSS2 Option

Utilize pseudo-elements. Add `position: relative;` to the `.current_page_item` (or `li` if you plan on using this for the hover). Then...

**New Answer (resolves IE bug)**

Adding the following code yields the results seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMrYF/8/). It differs from the original answer by having the pseudo-elements use their own bottom border to make the colors rather than the `background-color` of the pseudo-element. This seems to have resolved IE's stupidity.

```
.current_page_item:before,
.current_page_item:after,
.current_page_item a:before,
.current_page_item a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 20%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #4594cc;
}

.current_page_item:after {    
    left: 40%;
    border-bottom-color: #c4262e;
}
.current_page_item a:before {    
    left: 60%;    
    border-bottom-color: #d9709c;
}
.current_page_item a:after {    
    left: 80%;    
    border-bottom-color: #ffa100;
}

.current_page_item:hover {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}

.current_page_item:hover:before,
.current_page_item:hover:after,
.current_page_item:hover a:before,
.current_page_item:hover a:after {   
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**Original Answer (had bug in IE because it cannot seem to understand `height: 3px`)**

Adding the following code (not sure if you need the `hover` code for the current page or not, but I included if needed) yields the results seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMrYF/7/):

```
.current_page_item:before,
.current_page_item:after,
.current_page_item a:before,
.current_page_item a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 20%;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: #4594cc;
}

.current_page_item:after {    
    left: 40%;
    background-color: #c4262e;
}
.current_page_item a:before {    
    left: 60%;
    background-color: #d9709c;
}
.current_page_item a:after {    
    left: 80%;
    background-color: #ffa100;
}

.current_page_item:hover {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}

.current_page_item:hover:before,
.current_page_item:hover:after,
.current_page_item:hover a:before,
.current_page_item:hover a:after {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**NOTE:** I've noticed IE seems to have issues being intelligent enough to determine the difference between `3px` and `4px` height in some cases, which causes an annoying misalignment of `1px` at certain points.

Answer (score 2):

-snip previous answer-

Ok, so I came up with an alternative solution. I used five divs positioned at the bottom of each `li` with a width of 20%. Seems like an ugly solution, but hey, it works!

http://jsfiddle.net/VdMPL/6/

Comment: thanks, sorry for not explaining properly, I meant a line consisting of the 5 colours - I have updated the question with a mockup for you to see.

Comment: The `<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>` is just adorable.

Comment: @Tom, I'd say it's not a bad solution which solves the problem ;) Although I would recommend to create the elements dynamically via jQuery for instance

Comment: @skip405 it seems like necessary evil justified by the need to defeat the eldritch horror that IE6 undoubtedly is.

Comment: Updated it with some quick jQuery for you people :-P

Answer (score 1):

A few options

- Add a bg image rather than a bottom border (using a static image file).
- Add a linear gradient for the bg image (not supported on IE9 and earlier).
- Use the `border-image` style (not supported on IE9 and earlier).

If the hyperlinks aren't fixed width, you could set the `background-size` (not supported on IE9 and earlier), or add an img tag to each hyperlink (statically, or using JS or jQuery) and scale it to 100% width and fixed height.

Using a linear gradient would involve defining 10 gradient points (2 for each color) (assuming it's possible to specify more than 2 gradient points).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something unholy and use CSS Gradients. Here's a hacked together fiddle the only works in Safari/Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ASLs3/1/

But as others have said you should probably just use a background image.