# CSS: Stripe with multiple colors

Tags: border, css

I have a navigation bar and want it to have a border at the bottom like a multi-colored stripe. For example, Google uses a multi-colored stripe like this:

[image: Google multi-color stripe.]

Could I do this in pure CSS, or would I have to use something like `border-image`?

Comment: CSS only lets you use one color per border-side unfortunately. You're gonna have to use something like a border image. Or you could position four <div> just below your element with different IDs to manipulate their color.

Comment: (Like this? - http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/IFduh) *Edit* Ah, I see the image now. I don't think you could do this in pure css.

Comment: @harley - does your code look like the picture?

Comment: @j08691 No, for some reason the picture didn't load- it has now and I se it doesn't :)

Comment: I see, I guess it's better to use `border-image` to use a stripe image as the border.

Comment: It's somewhat possible but not supported in all browsers. Plus it's a load of work. I'd recommend using an image for ease and compatibility.

Comment: You can sorta do it like this: http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/ukzGA But this is obviously only partial.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936982/css-how-to-draw-a-multi-coloured-line/11938663#11938663) may be of some use to you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with a linear gradient. In addition to just plain colors, you can do gradients for each stop. For google's own stripe, the color stops would look like this, CSS color names used for clarity:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
  to right, 
  blue,
  blue 25%,
  red 25%,
  red 50%,
  orange 50%,
  orange 75%,
  green 75%);
```

You can play with background-position and background-size to make it smaller than just the full header size, or put it into an :after / :before element and change the size on that element.

Example of color stops with gradient:

http://codepen.io/tholex/pen/nCzLt

Comment: Added -moz- and -ms- (IE10+)

Comment: For more control over the angle, you can use 90deg (or 180deg etc depending on the angle you want) instead of left. It doesn't help in this situation, but it is useful to know.

Comment: @OlexPonomarenko: In FF 16+, you shouldn't use the syntax with -moz anymore, but the official one. The official one includes a "to" your example is missing: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: Very nice answer. Works perfectly. The reason there are two of each colour is due to where the colour starts and stops within the div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're much better doing this with a background image. You can keep the image really tiny by making each colour 1px wide and your image file 1px tall (they'll scale perfectly, with crisp edges).

An example:

```
.navigation-bar:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/stripe.png) repeat;
    background-size: 100% 1px;
}
```