# Multiple Color Border

Tags: jquery, border, css

Is there a way to create a border that has up to 3 colors dynamically? On my site, depending on which categories a post falls into, I would like the left border to show specific colors.
At the moment there are 15 categories.

For example, if the post falls into 1 category, the left border should be only the color corresponding to the category. If the post falls into 2 categories, the left border should be half one color and half another. Finally, if it falls into 3 or more categories, the left border should be 1/3 one color, 1/3 another color, and 1/3 last color corresponding to 3 of the categories.

Is this possible using CSS? Is it possible using jQuery?

Is there a way to do it without having to create classes for all the combinations/permutations of the category colors?

Will this require using border-images similar to this response: [CSS: Stripe with multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348108/css-stripe-with-multiple-colors)?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The only option CSS gives that is remotely close to what you want is a color gradient (such as those seen on this site http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).  So the best option would be to do what is mentioned in the post that you linked and provide several color images to get the effect.

Comment: CSS won't know about the categories unless they are associated with some sort of class, id or other distinguishing attribute.

Comment: Right now they all have class associated with a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the method you linked combined with some javascript. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kwcpr/).

#### The CSS

```
#post {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    background-size: 6px 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

#### The JS

You may pass any number of colors and it will set the border for you.

```
function setBorderColors()
{
    var bgStr = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom';
        inc = 1 / arguments.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    {        
        bgStr += ', color-stop(' + i * inc + ', ' + arguments[i] + '), color-stop(' + (i + 1) * inc + ', ' + arguments[i] + ')';
    }
    $('#post').css('background-image', bgStr + ')');
}
```

Hope that helps!

*Edit:* I should mention that this is *not* cross-browser. It can be adapted to be. It should only work in Chrome and Safari at the moment.

Comment: How would I make it cross-browser safe? Would I just need to add all the types of gradient (moz, o-, ms-)? And change the css sequentially?

Comment: How would I pass each post through a similar function? I need to do it on the fly, so it would need to be lightweight, and would need to recognize different amounts of arguments using classes

Comment: Yes to your first question, although each browser might have a weird syntax besides the prefixes, so make sure you check each one. To style each post individually I would pass the element as the first argument and adjust the `arguments` loop to start at 1. I can't really offer much advice without seeing your code but if you're still working on this I'd be happy to help.