# Conditional striped background with CSS

Tags: css, background-color

I have some DIVs that can be any of 5 colours depending on which classes the DIV has set. If it has more than one class set, there's a priority to determine which colour is used. I want to change this, so that we get *multiple* colours if multiple classes are set.

Now, one part of this is the UI/UX perspective, because stripes can be horrible to look at. If you have any recommendations, I'm all ears -- but that alone won't earn you an acceptance.

The other part is how to pull this off technically. I'd prefer to do this purely in CSS, and I'd prefer the solution to work on the DIV background colour, but exactly how is still open. It's possible to create [two-color stripes](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/), and it's possible to create [multi-coloured backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348108/css-stripe-with-multiple-colors), but it's not clear to me how to do this *in a dynamic fashion* as opposed to the hard-coded examples, *and* have the ...dynamismityness?... triggered via *element classes*.

Comment: provide your code you done so far.

Comment: Well ... the code we have is rather ugly; the attempts I've made have all been unsuccessful (and deleted again) I haven't yet had time to construct a "minimum viable product". But yeah I understand what you're saying. I just hoped someone would say say this was "simple, you just go like this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you could use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to obtain something like:

```
.one{
   background:#ff0000;  
 }

.one.two{
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#00ff00',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9*/ 
}

.one.two.three{
   background: rgb(255,0,0); /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 33%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 33%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 33%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 66%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 66%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 66%); /* FF3.6-15 */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 33%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 33%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 33%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 66%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 66%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 66%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 33%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 33%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 33%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 66%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 66%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 66%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't I then have to define in CSS _all_ the combinations of the five possible classes?

Comment: @KlaymenDK I think you should write the combinations that are relevant for you.. for example .one.two.three is the same as .one.three.two or .two.one.three etc?

Comment: ohhh I was not aware, that does reduce the scope! Thanks for the insight!

Comment: you can reduce the amount of written code using a preprocessor like scss

Comment: I've accepted your answer in recognition of your effort, although the final implementation ended up being completely different (on account of the project being written in PHP and HTML and CSS and JS and Handlebars and yet another framework...).

Answer (score 0):

You can USE `nth-child` option there you can specify for 1n, 2n, 3n and so on

```css
.container div {width:100px; color:#ffffff; padding: 5px;}
    .container :nth-child(1n){
        background: #F44336;
    }
    .container :nth-child(2n){
        background: #E91E63;
    }
    .container :nth-child(3n){
        background: #9C27B0;
    }
    .container :nth-child(4n){
        background: #673AB7;
    }
    .container :nth-child(5n){
        background: #009688;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```